# Trying to start mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to start MySQL on CentOS so I run service mysqld start but I get the following error:

Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon

When I look into the logs, this is what I get

```
101015 11:06:08  mysqld started
101015 11:06:08 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
101015 11:06:08 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
101015 11:06:08 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'table_open_cache=256'
101015 11:06:08  mysqld ended
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a version prior to 5.1.3 then I think it should be table_cache and not table_open_cache - you mention in a comment that you are running 5.1.x but that x could be quite important!

Try changing table_open_cache to table_cache and see if that fixes the issue

Jason

Answer (score 0):

What version MySQL are you running? Did you perhaps run into this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35346)?

Comment: I am running MySQL 5.1.x but I will check that link you sent right now.

Comment: Now, I can't even connect to mysql. I get ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Well from your log message above, it looks like mysql is starting, throwing that error, and quitting, so it stands to reason that you wouldn't be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to me out of the blue. I wasn't able to figure out why it happened, but editing `/etc/my.cnf` and commenting out the `table_open_cache` line let me start `mysqld` again. There may be a few other lines you have to comment out, so check your logs to see if any other variables are unknown.